# Configure Nginx to ignore a path in url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location, auto-versioning, ngx-http-rewrite-module

My website is at `/root/website/`, in it there is a folder `static` for static files, when the user visit: `/static/dfd99a5/xxx.js`, I wish to serve `/root/website/static/xxx.js`, how can I do this in nginx?

Comment: You could define a new location block and redirect from there. It would be best to post your config as well.

Comment: @wong2, has your question been resolved?  if yes, please accept&&upvote, if no, please clarify what's missing.

Comment: @wong2, thanks for accept!  is there something still missing from my solution or incomplete in any way?  if yes, let me know what is it.  if no, why was it not upvoted?  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) directive like so:

```
location ~ ^(/static)/[0-9a-f]+(/.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ $1$2 break;
}
```